# How can i get id of any photo on Facebook using api

Tags: c#, facebook

I want photo id of any image uploaded on Facebook. I have an access token of Facebook user with appropriate permission on my Facebook apps. I want to display photo(rather then profile picture) on my site for that i need photo id.

Answer (score 2):

when you make a call to facebook api to upload a photo, facebook returns you the Photo Id of the uploaded photo so you can save/use the same.

Answer (score 0):

use the graph api to get the the users photo like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_OR_PAGE_ID/photos

The ids are in the response. Make sure you have the user_photos read permission granted or it will not work.
[See this documentation for more](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)